# To achieve Kafka-mule integration using Mule 4, I installed zookeeper&kafka on my machine. Both the servers connection goes off after sometime

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, mulesoft

I started by creating zookeeper and kafka servers respectively on my machine. The connection gets established for both the servers but goes off after a few mins, throwing some errors.
**ZOOKEEPER ERROR LOG-**

```
'''2020-05-11 14:32:36,908 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:FileTxnLog@284] - Creating new log file: log.1
2020-05-11 14:36:05,170 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:NIOServerCnxn@373] - Close of session 0x10000cc587b0003
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:324)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory$IOWorkRequest.doWork(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:522)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.WorkerService$ScheduledWorkRequest.run(WorkerService.java:154)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-05-11 14:36:10,589 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@600] - Expiring session 0x10000cc587b0003, timeout of 6000ms exceeded
```

'''

**KAFKA ERROR LOG -** Below are the kafka server error logs## Heading ##

```
'''[2020-05-11 14:33:41,077] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-05-11 14:36:04,762] ERROR Error while writing to checkpoint file C:\Kafka\Kafkakafka-logs\replication-offset-checkpoint (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Kafka\Kafkakafka-logs\replication-offset-checkpoint.tmp -> C:\Kafka\Kafkakafka-logs\replication-offset-checkpoint
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:81)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
.....
[2020-05-11 14:36:04,776] INFO [ReplicaManager broker=0] Stopping serving replicas in dir C:\Kafka\Kafkakafka-logs (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2020-05-11 14:36:04,776] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=0] Error while writing to highwatermark file in directory C:\Kafka\Kafkakafka-logs (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Error while writing to checkpoint file C:\Kafka\Kafkakafka-logs\replication-offset-checkpoint
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Kafka\Kafkakafka-logs\replication-offset-checkpoint.tmp -> C:\Kafka\Kafkakafka-logs\replication-offset-checkpoint
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:81)
```

'''

Comment: Are you using more than one broker in the same machine? If yes, you are using the same directories structure to both. You trying to write a new file in an existent file. Is an approach for the problem. Another thing, if you see your directory `C:\Kafka\Kafkakafka-logs`, seems to be that you forgot an `\`.

Comment: Thanks William for replying. 
There is only one broker that is being used.
Also, I didnt get this line ->> Another thing, if you see your directory C:\Kafka\Kafkakafka-logs, seems to be that you forgot an ``. 
Can you please elaborate.